# Testing whether the levels of a qualitative variable are equally effective

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, qualitative

To ultimately increase the demand for Fresh Detergent, Enterprise Industries' marketing
department is conducting a study comparing the effectiveness of three different advertising campaigns. These campaigns are denoted as campaigns A = television commercials, B = balanced mixture of television and radio commercials, and C = balanced mixture of television, radio, newspaper and magazine ads. To conduct this study, Enterprise Industries randomly selected an advertising campaign that was used in each sales period as shown in the data below.

```
    'x1'    'x2'    'x3'    'x4'    'Y' Ad Camp.
3.85    3.8 5.5 -.05    7.38     B
3.75    4   6.75    .25 8.51     B
3.7 4.3 7.25    .6  9.52     B
3.7 3.7 5.5 0   7.5  A
3.6 3.85    7   .25 9.33     C
3.6 3.8 6.5 .2  8.28     A
3.6 3.75    6.75    .15 8.75     C
3.8 3.85    5.25    .05 7.87     C
3.8 3.65    5.25    -.15    7.1  B
3.85    4   6   .15 8    C
3.9 4.1 6.5 .2  7.89     A
3.9 4   6.25    .1  8.15     C
3.7 4.1 7   .4  9.1  C
3.75    4.2 6.9 .45 8.86     A
3.75    4.1 6.8 .35 8.9  B
3.8 4.1 6.8 .3  8.87     B
3.7 4.2 7.1 .5  9.26     B
3.8 4.3 7   .5  9    A
3.7 4.1 6.8 .4  8.75     B
3.8 3.75    6.5 -.05    7.95     B
3.8 3.75    6.25    -.05    7.65     C
3.75    3.65    6   -.1 7.27     A
3.7 3.9 6.5 .2  8    A
3.55    3.65    7   .1  8.5  A
3.6 4.1 6.8 .5  8.75     A
3.65    4.25    6.8 .6  9.21     B
3.7 3.65    6.5 -.05    8.27     C
3.75    3.75    5.75    0   7.67     B
3.8 3.85    5.8 .05 7.93     C
3.7 4.25    6.8 .55 9.26     C
```

Examine whether the three campaign strategies are equally effective, extending the model
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i4} + \beta_2 x_{i3} + \beta_3 x_{i3}^2 + \beta_4 x_{i3}x_{i4} + \varepsilon_i$$

to include the qualitative variable Advertising Campaign.

**Answer**: I've extended the model to
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i4} + \beta_2 x_{i3} + \beta_3 x_{i3}^2 + \beta_4 x_{i3}x_{i4} + \beta_5D_1 + \beta_6D_2 + \varepsilon_i$$

where
$$D_1 = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & , & {\rm Campaign \; B} \\ 0 & , & {\rm Otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$
$$D_2 = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & , & {\rm Campaign \; C} \\ 0 & , & {\rm Otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

I am capable of conducting the **R** analysis, however I do not understand what is meant by "test whether the three campaign strategies are equally effective".

Does this mean $H_0: \beta_5 = \beta_6$?

Comment: The question asks about "equally effective," not "equally likely."

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Any idea what does "equally effective" implies? Perhaps $H_0: \beta_5 = \beta_6$?

Comment: Because this is a textbook problem, we have to guess about its intentions.  Ordinarily the question of what "effective" means would be an important one and worthy of considerations of campaign cost and other things not in evidence in this question. But we can't do that, so we have to adopt the most primitive interpretation of "effective" as referring to the coefficients of the campaigns in the multiple regression.  Thus, $H_0$ must be the hypothesis that they all have the same coefficient. To express this correctly, pay attention to your dummy coding method--or use a more appropriate one.

Comment: Hmmm. I thought my dummy variables were defined in the "standard" way given that there are three levels of the qualitative variable. Are you suggesting that my model should be:
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i4} + \beta_2 x_{i3} + \beta_3 x_{i3}^2 + \beta_4 x_{i3}x_{i4} + \beta_5D_1 + \beta_6D_2 + \beta_7D_3 + \varepsilon_i$$

where 
$$D_3 = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & , & {\rm Campaign \; A} \\ 0 & , & {\rm Otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$ 

and I should be testing $H_0: \beta_5 = \beta_6 = \beta_7$?

Comment: That's a good approach. Your hypothesis is *almost* correct.  You need to remove $\beta_0$ from the model in order to make your parameters identifiable (and that is crucial for the hypothesis to be well-defined).

Comment: Much appreciated.

What do you mean identifiable? Why are three dummy variables needed in this case?

So the model should be
$$y_i = \beta_1x_{i4} + \beta_2x_{i3} + \beta_3x_{i3}^2 + \beta_4x_{i3}x_{i4} + \beta_5D_1 + \beta_6D_2 + \beta_7D_3 + \varepsilon$$

where $H_0: \beta_5 = \beta_6 = \beta_7$, because we these are the only terms relating to the qualitative variable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability

Comment: I have tried running an analysis in **R** with the proposed model, however I receive a N/A for the coefficient of the third dummy variable and always obtain a $\beta_0$. Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Details are needed, but I would venture a guess you did not explicitly remove the intercept from the formula.  That is done through the `+0` or `-1` syntax.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. Here is what I have obtained:

$$y = 9.0587x_4 - 6.5377x_3 + 0.5844x_3^2 + 25.8264D_1 + 25.9945D_2 + 25.9945D_3 - 1.1565x_3x_4$$

In regards to testing $H_0: \beta_5 = \beta_6 = \beta_7$, is it enough to look at the coefficients and say because they are approximately equal, then the three levels of the qualitative variable are approximately equally effective?